# Perform a single notify action at end of a Gulp array

Tags: gulp

How can I perform the `notify` action once when an array is passed to `src`?

```
 gulp.src('./files/*.swig')
   .pipe(rename({
     suffix: '.html'
   }))
   .pipe(notify('Templates rendered'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [onLast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify#options-onlast) method

```
 gulp.src('./files/*.swig')
   .pipe(rename({
     suffix: '.html'
   }))
   .pipe(notify({
     onLast: true,
     message: 'Templates rendered' 
   }));
```

Comment: Great. Looks like the syntax is a bit different according to docs so I edited your answer and marked it as correct. Perhaps you were using a diff version?

Comment: I got confused with gulp-notify.